# How to download Maven jars

Tags: java, maven, jar

I would like to have all the JAR files of Maven in my hard-drive to do some experiments. Is there any way to download all the jar files from Maven repository?

My operating system that i used is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by "all the JAR files of Maven", the Maven central repository contains gigs of jar files.  If you can explain further what you are trying to do then it will be easier to help.

If you have a maven project then you can run:

```
mvn clean install
```

from the directory where the pom.xml file is located.  Maven will download all of the dependencies required by the project to your computer, the default location is the .m2 directory under your user directory.

Another option is to use the maven dependency plugin to download all of the dependencies of a given project to a location.

Comment: What I am looking for is, downloading the JAR files into my local hard-drive. I don't want to use mvn command or eclipse stuff. What i want is one link to download the jar files from the repository if possible ?

Comment: You can download individual jar files, maven repositories have a web interface that allows searches. For example here is the results for junit http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjunit The search results will allow you to download the artifact jar.  However I don't see what downloading the jars from maven will get you.  Are you using the maven repositories as a convenient single source of libraries?

Comment: Answering your question, No, I would like to use jar files for research purpose as data-set for some special experiments !!

Answer (score 0):

Use a repository  manager like Nexus. http://nexus.sonatype.org/

Comment: there is no download link?

Comment: No, only a huge green in your face download button :/

Answer (score 0):

or Apache Archiva too http://archiva.apache.org/ :-)
See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+Repository+Manager+Feature+Matrix